# Finding all activated Site Features & Site Collection Features in a Site Collection Script

Tags: 2007, development, feature

I wonder if someone knows any C# script that will provide me all Site Features in a site collection as well as all Site collection features in a site collection.

I only required Activated features (GUID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that when you use the Feature property in a SPSite or SpWeb you only get the active features on the "site collection"/site. So the code under will give you the active features on a site collection and all the sites in that site collection (write it to a file so you do not miss any because of the cmd buffer).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(SPSite site = new SPSite(args[0]))
        {
            foreach (SPFeature feature in site.Features)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Site feature id {0}", feature.DefinitionId);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Web title {0}", web.Title);

                    foreach (SPFeature feature in web.Features)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Web feature id {0}", feature.DefinitionId);
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (web != null && web.Exists)
                        web.Dispose();
                }

            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7698/get-the-list-of-activated-features-in-the-site-collection-an.aspx

However, it only shows the guid and not the feature name.

Alternatively you use these scripts:-

Features are activated for an SPSite:

```
Get-SPFeature -Site http://sitecollectionurl | Sort DisplayName | FT DisplayName,Id
```

List all activated web scoped features

```
Get-SPSite http://sitecollectionurl | Get-SPWeb -Limit ALL | %{ Get-SPFeature -Web $_ } | Sort DisplayName -Unique | FT DisplayName,Id
```

Comment: isn't that powershell script ?

Comment: already went through that blog post, but I am looking for c# script not powershell, am afraid